# Get developers and others to work on game development team

Tags: unreal-engine4

Can somebody please give me advice on starting a development team?

Also, how do you recommend I go about communicating with and recruiting team members?

And finally, what is the best way to go about raising funds for this kind of project?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for project management advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could get on to kickstarter.com. It's a platform for fundraising for new projects. There is software section.